# Python, checking if string consists only of 1's and 0's

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write a function that checks if given string is binary or not. I'm using a while loop to browse characters in string one by one. If all of them are 0's or 1's it's going to return True, if anything is not  - break the loop and return False.
I've just written this tiny part of code, but it doesn't run. Why?

```
def fnIsBin(string):
    count = 0
    while count < len(string):
        character = string[count]
        if character == '0' or character == '1':
            print (count, character[count], "OK")
            count = count+1
            continue
        else:
            print (count, character[count], "ERROR")
            return False
            break
```

EDIT:
I also tried using 'set' to elude iterating with loop, but i don't quite get how does "set(string)" work. I got error that i cant consider it as a list. So how can I compare elements to 0 & 1?

```
def fnIsBin(string):
charactersList = set(string)
if len(charactersList) > 2:
    return False
else:
    if (charactersList[0] == '0' or charactersList[0] == '1') and (charactersList[1] == '0' or charactersList[1] == '1'): #there i made error, how to deal with it?
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't run"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Is that your actual indentation, or did you transcribe it badly?

Comment: Entering 1 character it works fine, but for 2 and more i'm getting following error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\~~\ghfhf.py", line 44, in <module>
    fnIsBin(binWord)
  File "C:\~~\ghfhf.py", line 26, in fnIsBin
    print (character[count], "OK")
IndexError: string index out of range

And yes, it's my actual intendation. Is it wrong? I'm begginer.

Comment: `character[count]` should be `string[count]`, or just `character`.

Comment: As an alternative (this isn't worth posting as an answer), `not s.replace('0', '').replace('1', '')` will return `True` if `s` only contains 0's and 1's, and `False` if not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing `OK` for each character that's `0` or `1`, even though there may be a later character that isn't. You need to wait until the end of the loop to know that it's really OK.

```
def fnIsBin(string):
    for character in string:
        if character != '0' and character != '1':
            print (character, "ERROR")
            return False
    print "OK"
    return True
```

There's no need for `break` after `return False` -- returning from the function automatically breaks out of the loop.

Comment: thank you, this is the clearest answer i got. :) i'm learning python from srtach on codecaemy and i doesn't get more complicated code i was given by the others. :)

Answer (score 7):

Your function fails because you never actually return `True`. That means if the string is actually binary, you'd return `None` which Python would consider as `False` in any boolean check.

Simply add `return True` at the end of the function.

As @Barmar mentioned in the comment, you also print the value of `character[count]` instead of `string[count]` which would cause `IndexError`.

An easier way to check if the string is binary would be:

```
test_string = '010101'
all_binary = all(c in '01' for c in test_string)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this:

Set:

```
fnInBin(s):
    return set(s).issubset({'0', '1'}) and bool(s)
```

Regular expression:

```
fnInBin(s):
    return bool(re.fullmatch('[01]+', s))
```

Integer conversion:

```
fnIsBin(s):
    try:
       int(s, 2)
       return True
    except ValueError:
       return False
```

The last one will strip whitespace from the input, though.

```
fnIsBin('\n 1   ') == True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `int` object and give it a base. It will fail if the object passed doesn't consist of a binary representation. Recall that a binary string is base 2.

```
def fnIsBin(string):
    try:
        binary_repr = int(string, 2)
    except ValueError as err
        print("error: {0}".format(err))
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: This allows for whitespace at the beginning and end of the string (which might be desired or not, just pointing it out).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the ways you could rewrite your function and maintain a similar structure (looping through each character):

```
def fnIsBin(string):
    for character in string:
        if not character in '01':
            return False
    return True
```

You could also do it using regular expressions:

```
import re
def fnIsBin(string):
    return re.match(r'^[10]+$', '01') is not None
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents (A short way):

```
test_string = '010101'
result = set(test_string) <= {'0','1'}
print(result)
```

Using set(test_string) converts the string into list of characters,

```
{0,1,0,1,0,1}
```

Using **<=** operator checks whether the set on the left-side is a proper subset of the set on the right-hand side

Ultimately checking whether there are only 0 and 1 are in the string or not in an in-direct and mathematical way.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a XOR solution to the mix:

```
bin_string = '010101'
for j in range(0, len(bin_string)):
    if int(bin_string[j]) != 0 ^ int(bin_string[j]) != 1:
        break
```